# Finding all Java beans that implement a particular interface

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I've been trying to write an EJB that scans the JBoss server that it is running on and comes up with a list of all available classes that implement a particular interface. This is easy in C# and I've seen a few examples in Java. However, the Java examples are designed for use in an Application container. I need something that works on JBoss.

I've tried playing with enumerating all available EJBs and haven't been able to make it work. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find this library useful http://code.google.com/p/reflections/

Using Reflections you can query your metadata such as:

- get all subtypes of some type
- get all types/methods/fields annotated with some annotation, w/o annotation parameters matching
- get all resources matching matching a regular expression

Comment: How do you envision this working with classes / interfaces already deployed in the server? Add all archives in jboss to the classpath of reflections?

Comment: Possibly. I believe you can create an index file in each jar to speed things up. It may help in deployment as well. I don't know if there is any you might need to do for JBoss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMX to connect with JBoss server & can get all beans that are deployed on the server.
Then as you can use reflection to verify further, implementation for particular interface etc.

Link : [How do I find out what port my jboss server is listening on programmatically using JBoss 4.2.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466518/how-do-i-find-out-what-port-my-jboss-server-is-listening-on-programmatically-usin/4508602#4508602) connection with JBoss using JMX. Then base on specific attributes, you can fetch information from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all implementations of some interface, you can use @Any annotation and Instance class.

Take a look at this: https://goo.gl/Kbn0bP