# Obtain information about jboss

Tags: java, jboss

How would one find out the jboss port programatically within application/war that is deployed on that jboss server? Using Java

It is a web service running, we don't have any user interface

Comment: In which context? If you are inside a servlet request context, simply calling request.getLocalPort() should give you what you want.

Comment: @pap I don't have servlet request context

Comment: Similar question, have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466518/how-do-i-find-out-what-port-my-jboss-server-is-listening-on-programmatically-usin/4508602#4508602

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you want the HTTP port.

JBoss publishes a Tomcat connector MBean for each web listener. The naming convention of the mbeans' ObjectNames is:

- Domain: **jboss.web**
- Attributes:

  - address: The binding address
  - port: The listening port
  - type: **connector**

The trick is, without making any assumptions about the bind address or port (the bind address could be 127.0.0.1, or 0.0.0.0 or a host name), finding the correct MBean. To do this, you can use a JMX Query that specifies:

1. The known domain name: **jboss.web**
2. The known type: **connector**
3. A wild card for the address: *****
4. A wild card for the port: *****
5. An attribute value expression that specifies you are looking for the **HTTP/1.1** protocol port (as opposed to the **AJP** port): **Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"), Query.value("HTTP/1.1"))**

Once you have an MBeanServerConnection to the JBoss MBeanServer, this statement will return the correct port:

```
String port = server.queryNames(
   new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Connector,address=*,port=*"), 
   Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"), Query.value("HTTP/1.1")))
   .iterator().next().getKeyProperty("port");
```

If you are attempting to determine the port from code running *inside* the JBoss JVM, acquiring the MBeanServerConnection is trivial since you can make a static call to [org.jboss.mx.util.MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss()](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/mx/util/MBeanServerLocator.html#locateJBoss%28%29).

Here is an example of a simple JSP to print the HTTP port number:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" import="java.util.*,org.jboss.mx.util.*,javax.management.*" %>
<html><head><title>JBoss Web Server Port</title></head><body>
<%
    try {
        MBeanServerConnection server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
        String port = server.queryNames(
            new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Connector,address=*,port=*"), 
            Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"), Query.value("HTTP/1.1")))
            .iterator().next().getKeyProperty("port");
        out.println("<p>Port:" + port + "</p>");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
%></body></html>
```

If you need to acquire this remotely, you need to use the JBoss client [RMIAdaptor](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.5/server/org/jboss/jmx/adaptor/rmi/RMIAdaptor.html). The [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466518/how-do-i-find-out-what-port-my-jboss-server-is-listening-on-programmatically-usin/4508602#4508602) provided by Nayan Wadekar is a good example of how to do this.

If your JBoss server has a [org.jboss.mx.remoting.service.JMXConnectorServerService](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/jboss/mx/remoting/service/JMXConnectorServerService.html) deployed or you are running JBoss using the [platform MBeanServer](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossMBeansInJConsole), you can also use the native JMX remoting. Here's a Groovy example of that:

```
import javax.management.*;
import javax.management.remote.*;
conn = null;
try {
    url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://njw810/jndi/rmi://njw810:1090/jmxconnector");
    conn = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
    server = conn.getMBeanServerConnection();
    objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.web:type=Connector,address=*,port=*");    // HTTP/1.1
    println server.queryNames(objectName, Query.match(Query.attr("protocol"), Query.value("HTTP/1.1"))).iterator().next().getKeyProperty("port");
} finally {
    try { conn.close(); println "Connection Closed"; } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```