# jboss as 7 query management port programmatically during webapp initialization

Tags: java, jboss

I've followed the advice in [Obtain information about jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6153661/obtain-information-about-jboss) question, to retrieve the management-port setting from JBoss during my webapp's startup `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized`.

This works fine when my webapp is deployed after JBoss was started, however it does NOT work when JBoss is started with the webapp already deployed, because the corresponding JBoss MBean `"jboss.as:socket-binding-group=standard-sockets,socket-binding=management-native"` is not yet registered, and I get a `InstanceNotFoundException` thrown.

Is it possible to defer the webapp initialization until JBoss is fully up and running (e.g. via an explicit dependency to a certain module, or some other mechanism) ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by simply spawning a thread to do what I wanted after start-up.

Comment: Please flesh out your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug:

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3557

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1114479

no workaround fount at this moment.